# How to get Email Alerts for Errors severity 17-25 on SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: errors, azure-sql-managed-instance, alerts

Discovered that In `Azure SQL Managed Instance`, there's no `Alerts` feature under SQL Server Agent.
According to documentation, Alerts feature for SQL Agent is not yet ready for MI.  Hopefully it will be ready sometime, but right now it isn't.

Tried Alerts under Monitoring in Azure portal, creating Alert rule there, but could not find anything related to Errors in database engine in a signal list there.

Also I know there are things like SQL Insights (preview), SQL Analytics (preview), Intelligent Insights - these work with Log Analytics Workspace and Diagnostic Settings. Possibly some of this provides alerting over email, need quite some time for research and testing.

The question is, how can I be alerted over email the moment errors severity 17-25 are happening in Azure SQL Managed Instance ? Steps how to configure it are welcome.